# Pusher Beam beamsClient.setUserId always gets {"error":"Unauthorized","description":"Invalid JWT signature"}

Tags: javascript, pusher

I am implementing Pusher Beam Notification in our application and I always get a 401 error response when calling beamsClient.setUserId. I can verify that the JWT token generated is correct. Any idea why?

Here is the code I'm using:

```
const token = "****";
const instanceId = "****";
const currentUserId = "****";

const beamsTokenProvider = new PusherPushNotifications.TokenProvider({
    url: "https://our-domain/pusher-beam-auth/",
    headers: {
        "Authorization": "Token " + token,
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }
});

const beamsClient = new PusherPushNotifications.Client({
    instanceId: instanceId,
});

beamsClient
.start()
.then(() => beamsClient.setUserId(currentUserId, beamsTokenProvider)) // I always get 401 error here
.catch(console.error);
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: It's `PusherPushNotifications.init` ig... after that you will get to client

Comment: @DreamyPlayer can you elaborate it more?

Comment: Check Request Headers on 2nd [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nAywA.png) Authorization says `Bearer` but you specificied `Token` in your code `"Authorization": "Token " + token,` this might causing Invalid Token as per 401 error.

Comment: @DreamyPlayer I've included the request headers of my 2nd request and you can see the value of "Authorization" is starting with Bearer.

Answer (score 1):

- This answer only as per docs.

```js
const currentUserId = "****";
const token = "****";
const instanceId = "****";

const tokenProvider = new PusherPushNotifications.TokenProvider({
  url: 'https://our-domain/pusher-beam-auth/',
  headers: {
    Authorization: 'Token ' + token,
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
});

PusherPushNotifications.init({
  instanceId: instanceId,
})
  .then(beamsClient => beamsClient.start())

  .then(beamsClient => beamsClient.setUserId(currentUserId, tokenProvider))

  .then(() => console.log('Successfully authenticated with Pusher Beams'))

  .catch(console.error);
```

Comment: Can you add the link to the docs? I get this error "Uncaught TypeError: PusherPushNotifications.init is not a function"

Comment: sorry seems i'm wrong checked wrong docs - [check here](https://pusher.com/docs/beams/getting-started/web/sdk-integration/#initialize-the-sdk) your code should work i will check again